# Hidan's Chakra Element

Tags: naruto

This question in simple: the only jutsus Hidan performs are related to Jashin. But this does not specify his chakra element.

[image]

What is Hidan's chakra nature?

Comment: religion ≠ chakra. Jashinism > elemental chakra + yin-yang. Kappa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here's the deal! Though his elemental chakra nature is unspecified ....since he uses a spiritual jutsu we can say that his chakra nature or more specifically his jutsu nature is "yin release" ..... (Like that of shadow bind of nara clan)
Update: It is not only yin but also "yang release" cause he share his physical damage too ... so it might be a "Yin-Yang release"

Comment: Its a plausible answer, but without relevant sources its hypothetical only. Suporting sources from Anime/Manga, quotes from Author etc. may help make it better.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find any such acclaim or quote about this so I used the concept of Yin-Yang release

Comment: Indeed, it was never given an explanation, but we do know that all non elemental jutsu are Yin, Yang, or Yin-Yang, though Yin-Yang is unlikely. Its probably rather a combination of multiple Jutsu of Yin or Yang, or a complex application of just one of them. Yin-Yang techniques all boil down to truth seeking ball related, or the Creation of all things. Hidans jutsu is clearly neither.

Comment: @Ryan You are right about yin-yang release but.....Since Hidan's jutsu first links his physical body with the victim through his jasin mark. So just like nara clan connect their shadow with their victim's shadow and manipulate them. We can say that Hidan can connect an invisible shadow i.e something governed by his imagination rather than physical object( something yin release does) and with that shadow he can share his physical damage (something yang release does) 
so we can say that it's both? Don't u agree?

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not mentioned in any of the manga, my *best guess* is that he has a water nature (or at least has a water nature) since he is a former ninja of Yugakure, the Village Hidden in Boiling Water.